# Why is the JSON output of my task being escaped by AWS Step Functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have a Lambda function that runs in a step function.

The Lambda function returns a JSON string as output.

When I debug the function locally, I see that the JSON is valid but when I run the step function and get to the next step after my function, I can see that all my `"` have turned to `\"` and there is a `"` at the beginning and end of my JSON.

So a JSON object that looks like the following when I debug my function:

```json
{"test":60,"test2":"30000","test3":"result1"}
```

Ends up looking like the following as the input of the step after my lambda:

```json
"{\"test\":60,\"test2\":\"30000\",\"test3\":\"result1\"}"
```

Why does my valid JSON object end up being escaped?

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: looks like the JSON is only being stringified. Can you share the codes?

Comment: I have a strange scenario where my output response form a lambda which is just a python dictionary is being jsonified now when it wasn't before and I do not perform the jsonification myself.. very odd.

Comment: you probable got it sorted by now, but what happened to me is that I set up my state machine definition using legacy lambda integration. I only realised this after using workflow studio which uses integrated API by default. that fixed my issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The Lambda function returns a JSON string as output.

**That is *exactly* why your JSON is being escaped - you're returning your object as a JSON *string* e.g. using `JSON.stringify` not as a JSON *object*.**

The easiest way to fix this would be to just return the object & not convert the output to a JSON string. That way, it won't be escaped & will be returned, as you expect, as an object.

However, if it must stay as a JSON string for whatever reason, you can use the `States.StringToJson(...)` [intrinsic function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) to unescape the escaped JSON string using the `ResultSelector` property of your task.

---

So for example, if your output is:

```json
{
    "Payload": "{\"test\":60,\"test2\":\"30000\",\"test3\":\"result1\"}",
    ...
}
```

To be able to unescape the output before passing it to the next task, set the `ResultSelector` of your task to:

```json
"ResultSelector": {
    "Payload.$":"States.StringToJson($.Payload)"
}
```

Or if using the Workflow Studio, click on the task, check the **Output** > **Transform result with ResultSelector - *optional*** checkbox and fill in the text box with the above `ResultSelector` object:

[image]

---

Either way, the final result of your task definition should look like this:

```json
{
  ...
  "States": {
    "Lambda Invoke": {
      "Type": "Task",
      ...
      "ResultSelector": {
        "Payload.$":"States.StringToJson($.Payload)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output will then be as you expect:

```json
{
  "Payload": {
    "test": 60,
    "test2": "30000",
    "test3": "result1"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would add, as part of a State Machine, there is only one reason I can think of to stringify your output. 'State' in state machines is kept by a Json Event passed to the next Task, so it really should be a Json object (the one reason I know if is if using NumPy and numpy.INF - which json.dumps and json.loads translate just fine to and from strings into INFINITY, aws json sees INFINITY and expects it to be a string, but it has no "" so it calls it an invalid json)

Comment: Agreed, JSON object output should be the way but in case needed, this answer caters to that scenario too! Thanks for the insight :)

Comment: This is great, was under the impression that it does the jsonify directly. Thank you!

Comment: @Xander More than welcome, glad I could help :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary - Towards the end, we removed all the JSON Serialization in the return types and left it to the APIs to handle this. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

While the answer from @Ermiya Eskandary is entirely correct, you also have a few more options that you can use to your advantage with or without using ResultSelector (if its a stringified json, then you pretty much have to use ResultSelector however as that answer mentioned) property. ResultPath and OutputPath.

If you do not need the incoming event for anything else after this Lambda, then have your lambda return an Json like object (ie: if in python, return a dict)

In your State Machine Definition, then include two properties in your Lambda Task

```
OutputPath:"$.SomeKey",
ResultPath:"$.SomeKey"
```

the SomeKey has to be the same for both.

What these two lines together in the task properties is say (ResultPath) "Put the output of this lambda in the event under the key 'SomeKey'" and then (OutputPath) "only send this key on to the next Task"

If you still need the data from the Input, you can use `ResultPath:` alone, which will put the output of the Lambda under the key assigned and append it to the InputEvent as well.

[See This documentation for more info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

Newbie to step functions here. I noticed there are two different ways to call a lambda from step functions:

The AWS-SDK way using `Resource: arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:lambda:invoke`

The "optimised" way using  `Resource: arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke`

I found that the optimized way does a much better job with the JSON coming back from the python Lambda whereas the AWS SDK way was an escaped mess.